# Loading HTML elements from template in separate file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to build a web page by loading HTML elements from a separate file using jQuery.

Files I have:

**index.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

**app.js**

```
$.get("template.html",function(data) {
    let a = $(data).contents().clone()
    let b = a.find("#par1")
    a.html()
    $("body").append(b)   
 })
```

**template.html**

```
<template>       
    <div>
      <p id="par1">apple</p>
      <p id="par2">banana</p>
    </div>    
</template>
```

When I load **index.html**, par1 from **template.html** is loaded into the body, and the word apple is rendered. This is what I want, but I can't figure out why I need the line "a.html()" in **app.js**. If I comment it out, I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null" at the line with `$("body").append(b)`. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from what is right and what is wrong in your code, here is explanation of what is happening in your code.

The error you are having is caused by appending a none DOM element to the HTML body, so if you `console.log(b, typeof b)` it will log the following:

```
k.fn.init [p#par1, prevObject: k.fn.init(3)] "object"
```

So what is happening here is that your code, `let a = $(data).contents().clone();` will create javascript object Array of your HTML tags, and assign it to `a` variable, then you are holding a reference to the array element in which it have the ID `par1`. and it is still an javascript `Object`, so when you call a.html() it will convert all `a` elements to Text and `DOM` elements, and `b` variable is holding a reference to one of those HTML elements, so that's why your code need a.html() or you can also have it like the following:

```
$.get("template.html",function(data) {
    let a = $(data).contents().clone();
    let b = a.find("#par1")
    $("body").append(b.html())   
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I still don't get why a.html() modifies a though. The docs state that it _returns_ the html content of the variable. I'm new to javascript so maybe that is just the way it does things?

Comment: I believe this is more of how javascript deals with variables and also how [contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/), [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) functions works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `a.html()` is not the one rendering the "apple" to the body?

I tried this in the here: https://codepen.io/BenKennish/pen/BtwEn

And the `$(data).contents().clone()` seems to be not working (so, b is empty). `$(data).clone()` on the other hand works.

I have no clear answer to your question other than that the list `contents()` returns is probably not something you can `find()` on.